# Powershell - Issues with -WrapText using Import-Excel Module

Tags: powershell

I'm running a Powershell script which turns some SQL output from .txt to somewhat easy to read Excel files.

The issue I am having, is some of the .txt output has rather long lines in certain columns as line breaks are replaced with '\n'. I've been able to replace the \n with a line break which, correctly, keeps the text within the same cell.

I would like to use -WrapText on those columns, and as of now, I am simply using the -WrapText command on the whole sheet(s). This, unfortunately, sometimes wraps the text when I don't want/need it to.

Is there a way I can use -WrapText, but have it only wrap to the minimum of a cell length, so it doesn't wrap too early? This would hopefully resolve my issue and only wrap on cells which have multiple lines.

Other solutions welcome if there is a better way around this issue. Relevant code below:

```
 $exportExcelSplat = @{

            AutoSize   = $true
            AutoFilter = $true
            BoldTopRow = $false
            PassThru   = $true
            Path       = $excelFilePath
        }
 
        $xlsx = $content |
            ForEach-Object { $_.TrimStart('|') } |
            ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|' |

                                                ForEach-Object {
                                                                                $_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {                                                                                               $_.Value = $_.Value -replace '\\n', [System.Environment]::NewLine
                                                                                }

            $_

                                                }|

            Export-Excel @exportExcelSplat

        foreach ($wsheet in $xlsx.Workbook.Worksheets) {
            1..$wsheet.Dimension.Columns | ForEach-Object {
                $setExcelColumnSplat = @{
                    HorizontalAlignment = 'Left'
                    VerticalAlignment   = 'Top'
                    ExcelPackage        = $xlsx
                    WorksheetName       = $wsheet.Name
                    Column              = $_

                }

                Set-ExcelColumn @setExcelColumnSplat -WrapText

            }

        }

        Close-ExcelPackage $xlsx
 
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd-HHmm'
        $archiveFileName = "{0}_{1}.txt" -f $_.BaseName, $timestamp
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination (Join-Path $archiveFolderPath $archiveFileName)

    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.